# View with COUNT, GROUP BY and HAVING not displaying

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, group-by, asp.net-mvc-5

I set up a view on my database to keep track of activity, grouping by date and counting per user. The date is a `DateTime` column so I had to convert it to use only the date portion. Within the database the data in the view is correct, but when the view is displayed in `MVC5` it displays some of the data more than once.

Select query for the view:

```
SELECT TOP(100)PERCENT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateCompleted),0) AS WorkDate, UserName, Count(UserName) AS Total
FROM dbo.Queue
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateCompleted),0), UserName, Status
HAVING (Status = N'Completed')
ORDER BY WorkDate
```

In MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Activity()
{
    IQueryable<Activity> activity = db.Activity.OrderBy(a => a.WorkDate).ThenBy(a => a.UserName);
    return View(activity);
}
```

In the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Activity>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WorkDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
    </th>
  </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Strangely, the database has 22 rows in its result set and the view is also showing 22 rows, but its showing the same rows two or three times and not showing some of the rows at all. Any help to get to the bottom of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are yuo 100% sure that the data in those 22 displayed rows are duplicated?

Comment: You could just cast or convert your datetime column as a date. Would be far simpler code. I don't quite understand where or what the issue is. Is the problem in the sql view or the mvc view?

Comment: @SeanLange: Tried to cast as date but got an error along the lines that it couldn't process date methods. Data in the SQL view is fine so the problem must lie at the MVC end I think.

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, SQL view has one row per user per date, as you would expect. MVC view is displaying the same user on the same date several times, in a seemingly random order. Data is sorted by date and so dates should run consecutively but they cut back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer that solves your problem but you have some issues in your view. The top 100 percent is NOT going to do what you think it will. I assume you added that because you want your view "ordered" and you get an error message when there is an order by but no top in a view declaration. The problem here is that adding an order by in a view does NOT guarantee the output from the view will be returned in that order. In fact, it logically doesn't even make sense. What if you have two view in a single query and they both have an order by clause that contradict each other? Which one wins? The ONLY way to ensure order of a query result is to use an order by on the select statement, not the underlying view.

```
SELECT --TOP(100)PERCENT 
    CAST(DateCompleted as Date) AS WorkDate
    , UserName
    , Count(UserName) AS Total
FROM dbo.Queue
WHERE Status = 'Completed'
GROUP BY CAST(DateCompleted as Date), UserName
--ORDER BY WorkDate
```

Comment: I didn't add the TOP(100)PERCENT, the system did that itself as I added the select columns. Your select statement gives me an SQL Execution Error: Cannot call methods on date.

Comment: Ahh you must have used the GUI to "create new view". I never use that tool as I can just create the query faster by hand than using the visual tool. I am curious what the message is that you get. The message you stated does not look like a sql server error message.

Comment: Actually it turns out this is a bug in SSMS with the view designer. No wonder I couldn't figure this out. If you write your view in sql instead of the designer this issue goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sean. SO has now marked my question as a duplicate and pointed to an answer where the key for the view being used by EF was not unique. I forced it to use a composite key and that seems to have solved it for me.